# WPF: bind to property of nested object

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

My control (`MyControl`) based on `UserControl`. It contains `ListBox` item, named as `myListBox`. I placed `MyControl` instance on window as a `myControlInstance` variable. This window contains and other control, named as `appInfo` variable. I need binding the `appInfo.SomeProperty` with a `MyControl.myListBox.SelectedItem`. How can I do it through XAML?

I try it:

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myControlInstanceName, 
Path=myListBox.SelectedItem}"
```

But it ain't working. How can I solve it problem through XAML?

Comment: I solve it via next XAML code: `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myControlInstanceName, Path=Content.Children[1].SelectedItem}"/>`. But I would like to do without using of index...

Comment: It's better approach realize SelectedItem as DependencyProperty in you control.

Comment: You might need to expose `myListBox` as a `Property` in your UserControl. As far as I know, WPF can only bind to properties, not to fields. (Of course, you could directly expose `myListBox.SelectedItem` as a property of your UserControl, but then you might have to implement change notifications yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it via next XAML code: `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myControlInstanceName, Path=Content.Children[1].SelectedItem}"`